# Select text between two bookmarks in Komodo Edit

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

Let's say I have the following (example) code in `combined.js`:

```js
/* jQuery, Moment.js, Bootstrap, etc. */

Child.prototype.doSchool = function(data) { // Bookmarked
    var essay = data.essay || {};

    if (essay) {
        var spelling = checkSpelling(essay, EN_US_GRADE_7);

        return spelling.grade();
    }
}

/* Extensive and Turing-complete code base */

var burt = new Child();
if (burt.doSchool({essay: "i like trains"}) < .65) burt.comfort(); // Bookmarked

/* jQuery extensions, Fallout 4, etc. */
```

The file is bookmarked in Komodo Edit 9.3.x in the locations marked by `// inline comments`.

Any `/* block comments */` indicate thousands of lines of code.

The source between the bookmarks exists in another file, `school.inc.js`. I want to know if there is an easy way to select all the text between the bookmarks, so that `combined.js` can be easily updated by pasting the contents of `school.inc.js` over it without having to use a combining utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this but you could possible do it by writing a Userscript.

You'll want to use the [Komodo Editor SDK](http://docs.komodoide.com/SDK/api/commonjs/editor).

```
// This assumes you're running the Userscript starting at the first bookmark
var editor = require("ko/editor");
var startSelect;
var endSelect;
var done = false;

function selectBookmarkRegion(){
    if(editor.bookmarkExists()) { // check if bookmark is set on current line
        startSelect = { // save it's line start
                line: editor.getLineNumber(),
                ch: 0
            }; 
    } else {
        alert("Start me on a line with a Bookmark");
    }

    editor.goLineDown();
    while(!done){
        if(editor.bookmarkExists())
        {
            endSelect = {
                line: editor.getLineNumber(),
                ch: editor.getLineSize()
            };// Save line end
            done = true;
        }
        editor.goLineDown();
        // found a bug as I was writing this.  Will be fixed in the next releases
        if (editor.getLineNumber() + 1 == editor.lineCount())
        {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    editor.setSelection(startSelect, endSelect); // Wrap the selection
}

selectBookmarkRegion();
```

Comment: Hey no worries!  Glad I could help.